# Html + JavaScript + CSV parsing + Google Charts help oh joy xD ...

Tags: javascript, html, csv, google-visualization

So I am trying to make a program that will take a csv file and generate a google chart, it deals with listing current virtual machines, then how much memory in gb they have used vs how much is free. I am pretty noob with javascript and spent most my work day trying to get this crap so any help is highly appreciated! So currently what I used is jquery.csv-0.71 extension. and to give you a sample of my csv I will just paste some right here:

```
"Name","UsedSpace","Capacity"
"GVLVNX00","378","500"
"GVLVNX01","421","500"
"GVLVNX02","351","500"
"GVLVNX04","421","500"
"GVLVNX05","283","500"
```

With that sample in mind and the knowledge of my helper jquery csv file what is going wrong now in here. I am sure there are lots, and one error I get is related to the horizontal data cant be a string? Which makes no sense, I want the VM names to go on the x axis derp :/ ... But otherwise here is the code. My goal is to make a graph that actually has the bars overlap and I know this one doesn't have that but its at least a start. I could not even find any that had the bars overlap like I wanted to show free vs used memory but if you find a graph better suited please show me the code to accomplish it :) . So here is my html / javascript portion some might be commented out etc cause I was getting an error or debugging. Sorry if you read all that, I ramble slightly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Google Chart Example</title>
   <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>

   <script>
   // load the visualization library from Google and set a listener
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
   // grab the CSV
   $.get("DBdatastores.csv", function(csvString) {

   // transform the CSV string into an array
    var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString);

    // this new DataTable object holds all the data
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

    var options = {
          title: 'Virtual Machine Storage(GB)',
          hAxis: {title: "Virtual Machine Names", titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        //  vAxis: {title: "Memory In GB", minValue: 0, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(2).max}
        };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
     });
    }
   </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart">

   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help if anyone knows how to do this kinda crap, I am a php/mysql dev this is
not my ideal task haha.

Comment: That title is not googlable, can you update the title to be more specific so it will be helpful to others in the future?

Comment: If I get it solved I will edit the title a bit better, for now it doesn't matter haha this code doesn't work :| .

Comment: Right now, no one has any idea what the actual issue is by reading your title. Updating it will draw more attention and you will get a solution faster. I edited it myself but I don't really know google chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely in one of two places: either in your CSV file, or with the jQuery CSV plugin.  Your "UsedSpace" and "Capacity" data series are being interpreted as "string" type, which isn't valid to draw a chart with - they must be "number" type.  The first thing I suggest is removing the quotes from around your numbers in the CSV:

```
"Name","UsedSpace","Capacity"
"GVLVNX00",378,500
"GVLVNX01",421,500
"GVLVNX02",351,500
"GVLVNX04",421,500
"GVLVNX05",283,500
```

You then need to tell the jQuery CSV plugin to parse your data as numbers when possible:

```
var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {
    onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, So I was looking here. I was looking here http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/examples/google-visualization.html And gave the data "Name","UsedSpace","Capacity"
GVLVNX00,378,500
GVLVNX01,421,500
GVLVNX02,351,500
GVLVNX04,421,500
GVLVNX05,283,500
GVLVNX06,59,100
yet this thing still wont allow it? I see google chart examples where the column names are strings and not numbers, so why wont it allow this :/ ?

Comment: That's a poor example to use with your data, as it has a ChartRangeFilter control that requires your domain data to be type "number".  If you format the data in your CSV like in my example (quote all strings, leave numbers unquoted), your chart should draw.

Comment: So I modified that CSV to look just like yours now, did not fix it. I ended up starting to debug by commenting out portions of code and just alert() out various vars, right now I am alerting arrayData, and I get Name,UsedSpace,Capacity,GVLVNX00,378,500,GVLVNX01,421,500,GVLVNX02,351,500 etc. I still get the error Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string when I run the entire program. This stuff sucks.  UPDATE- I also alert() out the data var after running the array to data table and got [object Object] .. So something isn't right here.

Comment: `[object Object]` is what I would expect to see from alerting a DataTable.  Is the javascript in your question the same as what you are using now?  If it isn't, can you update your question with your current code (leaving out `alert` calls - they don't matter)?

Comment: The problem is in the CSV parsing - you need to tell the CSV plugin to cast your data as numbersby passing `{onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar}` as a second parameter to the `$.csv.toArrays` call.  I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: OMG I deleted that at one point thinking it was going to mess with my VM name values, now I just tested and added it back and it worked. Thanks man you are awsome!

Comment: jquery-csv author here. Since Google Code shutdown the project has been migrated to http://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv.